# Change all node_modules build.gradle dependencies to match gradle 7.x

Tags: android, react-native

I have updated my project from react-native **0.63.3** to **0.68.1** and so on gradle from **4.x** to **7.x** and I have an issue with different *node_modules* that are still using `compile` in their build.gradle *dependencies* that giving me an error :
`Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

To fix this issue I just have to replace `compile` with `implementation` but every time my *node_modules* are rm for some reason I have to apply this fix.

Someone have a suggestion to avoid doing it every time?

Comment: What do you need the upgrade for? I would never recommend changing the built-in native tooling.

Comment: I don't understand your question, I need to upgrade my react-native version ?